# once elements are removed from an array how can we add them back?

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, push, element

I had some help from a person yesterday, very helpful, basically I am removing null or blank elements from my dropdown list that is generated.  This dropdown changes with an onchange handler, if there are blanks that show up then they are removed but once the onchange takes place then I can't get back those elements that might have values this time.

So I want to remove the elements and then add them back again especially if they are not blanks, I am using removeChild to remove them, I think there is something with the push to put them back but am not sure how.  Here is the code I have:

```
for(var index = document.pickDivision.field1.options.length - 1; index >= 1; index--)
{
    alert(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index])
    if(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value=='')
    {
        document.pickDivision.field1.removeChild(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index]);            
    }
```

Comment: Removed the PHP `echo` statements, since they're not relevant to this question. Rendered HTML/JS is the important thing here.

Comment: you need to maintain a backup or work on the copy

Comment: How would a removed blank element suddenly not be blank and need to be added back? (Note that `options` is not an array.)

Comment: ok, so I would have to maintain a working copy or backup?  So an example here is when the user selects something in the dropdown then 1 value comes back leaving 6 other elements blank, so these are removed.  Now the user wants to make another selection and now 6 values should come back but they don't because the elements that were blank are gone